CEC when Raspberry PI is in an inactive port on AV receiver
My Raspberry Pi (1 B+, with Raspberry OS Bookworm) is connected to one of 7 HDMI inputs on my AV Receiver (Pioneer SP-1223) (HDMI6). There are other devices in other inputs, Chromecast on HDMI7, a Playstation in HDMI4, TV with ARC, DVD player in their own inputs, that Pioneer calls just TV, DVD, etc.
I am trying to attach some automation to the Raspotify (to turn on the receiver and switch it to HDMI6 upon connection to Raspotify, for example). The wireup there works, but I'm struggling with the CEC. I'm testing both cec-client and cec-ctl, and in both cases it appears that the results are radically different depending on whether HDMI6 is selected on the receiver.
ON and STANDBY towards the receiver (as audio device) works always, regardless the input.
But other commands, including "scan" seem to misbehave if a different port is selected on the receiver. I'm getting a lot of "64 host down" errors, and pretty much nothing else works. If HDMI6 is selected, I seem to be able to switch away from it via CEC, and then we are back to "nothing works".
The worst part is that I seem to remember having the same setup working before (I am recreating a system that I once had running). I am starting to suspect that the receiver is somehow the offending part here, maybe I am missing some obscure setting or something... Does this ring any bells for somebody?
It seems that Raspberry OS's internals are able to talk to HDMI correctly, at least it would turn on the TV on startup (unless I disable that in config).
EDIT:
Let me show some output.
The receiver is in STANDBY:
yuri@raspberrypi:~ $ echo "scan" | cec-client -t p -s -d 1
== using device type 'playback device'
opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
requesting CEC bus information ...
CEC bus information
===================
device #0: TV
address:       0.0.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        LG
osd string:    TV
CEC version:   1.3a
power status:  standby
language:      eng


device #4: Playback 1
address:       1.6.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        LG
osd string:    CECTester
CEC version:   1.3a
power status:  on
language:      eng


device #5: Audio
address:       1.0.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        Pioneer
osd string:    RECEIVER
CEC version:   1.4
power status:  standby
language:      ???


currently active source: unknown (-1)

The receiver is ON, selected source is HDMI7 (in which a Chromcast sits, if it matters. Although it is same if one of other HDMIs is selected)
yuri@raspberrypi:~ $ echo "scan" | cec-client -t p -s -d 1
== using device type 'playback device'
opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
ERROR:   [            8722]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [            8722]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           13042]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           13042]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
requesting CEC bus information ...
CEC bus information
===================
device #4: Playback 1
address:       1.0.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        Pulse Eight
osd string:    CECTester
CEC version:   1.4
power status:  on
language:      eng


currently active source: unknown (-1)
ERROR:   [           26002]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26002]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26002]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26002]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26002]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26002]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26002]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26002]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26002]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26002]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26002]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26003]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26004]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26004]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
ERROR:   [           26004]     CLinuxCECAdapterCommunication::Write - ioctl CEC_TRANSMIT failed - tx_status=00 errno=64
yuri@raspberrypi:~ $


Selecting HDMI6 again, I guess Chromcast woke up on 1.7.0.0 when I previously switched to HDMI7, but scan works as it should again:
yuri@raspberrypi:~ $ echo "scan" | cec-client -t p -s -d 1
== using device type 'playback device'
opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
requesting CEC bus information ...
CEC bus information
===================
device #0: TV
address:       0.0.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        LG
osd string:    TV
CEC version:   1.3a
power status:  standby
language:      eng


device #4: Playback 1
address:       1.7.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        Google
osd string:    Chromecast
CEC version:   1.4
power status:  on
language:      ???


device #5: Audio
address:       1.0.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        Pioneer
osd string:    RECEIVER
CEC version:   1.4
power status:  on
language:      ???


device #8: Playback 2
address:       1.6.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        LG
osd string:    CECTester
CEC version:   1.3a
power status:  on
language:      eng


currently active source: unknown (-1)
yuri@raspberrypi:~ $



Run cec-client -l to list all available HDMI CEC devices. Confirm that the Pi is recognized.

cec-client -l shows local hdmi devices, no? what's there to be "recognized"? In my case it shows /dev/cec0 as, I suppose, it should.
echo "scan" > cec-client -t p -s -d 1
shows 3 devices, 0.0.0.0 TV, 1.0.0.0 sound system (the receiver) and 1.6.0.0 raspberry, which is correct, seen as we are in HDMI6. The problem is, as soon as the AV is on and switches to another port, same scan shows a bunch of 64 errors - that's what the question is about.
